# Select element whose name is contained in another node?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML

```
<DateInfo date="2016/02/02 13:11:12">
  <Year>2016</Year>
  <Month number="2">February</Month>
  <Day ofMonth="2" ofYear="33">Tuesday</Day>
  <Hour am="false" pm="true">13</Hour>
  <Minute>11</Minute>
  <Second>12</Second>
  <Monday is="false" numInMonth="0" firstInMonth="false" lastInMonth="false" />
  <Tuesday is="true" numInMonth="1" firstInMonth="true" lastInMonth="false" />
  <Wednesday is="false" numInMonth="0" firstInMonth="false" lastInMonth="false" />
  <Thursday is="false" numInMonth="0" firstInMonth="false" lastInMonth="false" />
  <Friday is="false" numInMonth="0" firstInMonth="false" lastInMonth="false" />
  <Saturday is="false" numInMonth="0" firstInMonth="false" lastInMonth="false" />
  <Sunday is="false" numInMonth="0" firstInMonth="false" lastInMonth="false" />
  <WeekDay is="true" isFirstWeekDay="false" isLastWeekDay="false" />
  <Weekend is="false" />  
  <DueDay>Tuesday</DueDay>
</DateInfo>
```

How can I get the value of the `firstInMonth` attribute of the element whose name is the value of the `<DueDay>` element?

For example, `DueDay` is `Tuesday` so I want to get the value of the `firstInMonth` attribute for the element `Tuesday`, i.e. 'true'.

I am working in an existing framework and don't have access to XPath 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the `@firstInMonth` attribute of the child of `DateInfo` whose name is given by the `DueDay` child, use this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/DateInfo/*[name() = ../DueDay]/@firstInMonth
```

For your XML this will select `true`, as requested.